# A possible new integral rule

Tags: calculus

Is there a non-constant continuous elementary function f defined everywhere on the reals, where f has elementary antiderivatives, such that for every elementary g with elementary antiderivatives, the product of f and g also has elementary antiderivatives?

Comment: Isn't't it the integration byparts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the general case i'm afraid not, but if $g$ is can be integrated twice over $\mathbb{R}$ then you can use integration by parts to prove that such a function exists:

$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}$
$f(x)=ax$

Comment: Proof of "in the general case i'm afraid not" ?

Comment: in the general case, if $f$ exists then composition holds  
$\exists A: \frac{dA}{dx}=f(x)g(x) \implies \exists K: \frac{dK}{dx}=f(x)A(x)$ and although i'm not good enough to provide a rigorous argument that counts as a proof, i think this might start to convince you.